# styling svgs that are inline of css

Tags: css, svg

```
.player
{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 10 10'><line x1='1' y1='1' x2='9' y2='9' stroke='red'/><line x1='1' y1='9' x2='9' y2='1' stroke='red'/></svg>");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.one
{
    fill: black;
}
.two
{
    stroke: white;
}
```

Elements with the `player` class will have a background image that is an svg. If there are elements with both the `player` and the `one` or `two` class, is it possible to change the style of the svg if it's inlined like so? If not, how would I do a simple color change by having classes? Ideally, I wouldn't want to introduce any more markup in the html and prevent http accesses for such a small svg file.

Answer (score 2):

As Douglas wrote, you can style only IMG elements with inline "src".

I use this technique:

Use common image with the path to your SVG:

```
<img src="my.svg" alt="">
```

Transform the "src" to inline style using JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
        }
        // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }

        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Replace image with new SVG
        $img.replaceWith($svg);

    }, 'xml');
});
```

Style your SVG using CSS:

```
path {
    fill: #f00;
}
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify your SVG with CSS, you have to use inline SVG, you can't modify it with a class if you use it as a background-image to an element.

If you want to make your authoring look cleaned up you can use a server side script to push the SVG's markup to your page (such as PHP's file_get_contents()).

Since there's no way around this, just compress your SVG as much as possible (I like [this tool](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/), there's some other good ones on the source I attached) and then write your svg as cleanly as possible, it shouldn't be that bloated looking if it's a small file.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Sorry I couldn't be the bearer of better news.